# How to programmatically make an iframe and parse its HTML after complete load

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to run the following code in my browser console:

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
iframe.src = 'https://same.domain.tld/path';
iframe.onload = () => {
  const html = iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  const tag = doc.querySelector('div');   
  if (tag) {
    console.log('Tag detected, processing...');
    ...
  }
  document.body.removeChild(iframe);
};
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

But I receive an error for the last line:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')

P.S. I have no access to the backend server but I'm authenticated, that's why I run this code in the browser console of the website.

---

**Update 1:** Well, I made some progress... By adding a delay I could get the HTML content although the error is still there:

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
iframe.src = 'https://same.domain.tld/path';
iframe.addEventListener('load', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const html = iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    const tag = doc.querySelector('div');   
    if (tag) {
      console.log('Tag detected, processing...');
      ...
    }
    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
  }, 1000);
});
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

---

**Update 2:** Since the result HTML didn't include all DOM changes done by javascript, I modified the script to wait for that as well:

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
iframe.src = 'https://same.domain.tld/path';

let pageLoaded = false;
let domLoaded = false;

iframe.addEventListener('load', () => {
  pageLoaded = true;
  checkStatus();
});
  
iframe.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  domLoaded = true;
  checkStatus();
});

function checkStatus() {
  if (pageLoaded && domLoaded) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const html = iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
      const tag = doc.querySelector('div');   
      if (tag) {
        console.log('Tag detected, processing...');
        ...
      }
      document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    }, 1000);
  }
};
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

But now I don't get any HTML, still have the same error, and get a new CORB warning although the website I'm running this script on and the URL of the iframe are on the same domain name at its root.

Answer (score 1):

if the iframe's onload event fires before the iframe is appended to the document (which can happen if the iframe loads very quickly), the onload function will not be called,and above code doesn't work.

you can have a flag to check if iframe is already loaded then do accordingly. check the below code.

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 iframe.style.display = 'none';
 iframe.src = 'https://same.domain.tld/path';
 
 let iframeLoaded = false;
 iframe.onload = () => {
   iframeLoaded = true;
   const html = iframe.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
   const parser = new DOMParser();
   const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
   const tag = doc.querySelector('div');   
   if (tag) {
     console.log('Tag detected, processing...');
     ...
   }
   document.body.removeChild(iframe);
 };
 
 document.body.appendChild(iframe);
 
 if (iframeLoaded) {
   // If the iframe has already loaded, call the onload function immediately.
   iframe.onload();
 }
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I previously tried to append the iframe before adding its attributes, but that wasn't successful. Your code didn't help either, and tbh I don't understand how it's addressing the issue since the error is occurring on the appendChild line.